# VirtueMart Checkout Quantities

Tags: joomla, checkout, virtuemart

Good morning

I would like to know if there is a way in VirtueMart to make orders only be able to be places in increments of 4, one of the sites i am working can only ship the products in boxes of 4 and it is difficult if it is not.

I would like to know how i would be able to change this, is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I would not like it to 4 of the same item, but in general there needs to be 4 items it can be the same item or different items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a "step" for each product, with the "Purchase Quantity Steps" property. So, for a given product, you can purchase only 4, or 8, or 12...

You **cannot** set a "step" that apply to different products, i.e. so that the total of items in your cart you can only be 4, or 8, or 12 ...

Of course I'm talking about VirtueMart core; there may be extensions that make it possible, but I don't know them. And of course as a developer you may extend VirtueMart as you wish, but that's a different topic.

Comment: Do you have any extensions in mind that might be able to do this?

Comment: I wrote "there may be extensions that make it possible, but I don't know them.". So no, I don't. Sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, i will see if i can find an extention or see what else i can find out.